# Cannot upgrade to Lion using DVD

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, upgrade

When I first setup my MBP on 10.6 I made a lot of newb mistakes, and was unable to get Ruby on Rails to install, amongst a lot of other things. Because of this, I decided to backup everything on to a Time Machine HDD and re-install Lion.

I had a bunch of problems but managed to sort them out, requiring me to go back to 10.6 from the original disc that came with the MBP.

Before I did anything however, I burnt the Lion installer that I got from the App Store to a DVD. Now though, when I try to run it, I get the following:

> Cannot download additional components.

I've managed to download software updates, so I know it can connect to the Apple servers.

Comment: Why not install 10.6 and then upgrade the normal way?

Comment: What is the normal way? My internet connection isn't very good and takes an age.

Comment: Downloading via internet. Well, there could be a million reasons for this. The error message, as far as I remember, could occur for a lot of causes, from hardware issues to software ones – when exactly does it appear? At which step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to solve this by using my Time Machine backup of the install file. Running this worked fine and updates after upgrading downloaded ok - in time.

Strange since it's probably all coming from the same source, but nonetheless it worked.